# Can not add parameter to Dockerfile RUN command

Tags: .net, docker, msbuild, nuget

I am creating a Dockerfile to build and deploy an ASP.NET 4 application. I have this code:

```
#Use the add-msbuild image that has msbuild.exe installed. This image inherits from microsoft/iis.
FROM add-msbuild

#Make a folder in the container that will contain the application.
RUN mkdir "C:\site"
RUN mkdir "C:\site\packages"
RUN mkdir "C:\build"

#Copy the application source code to the build folder.
COPY . "C:\build"
WORKDIR "C:\build"

#Build the application.
RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore"]  
RUN ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\12.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe", "C:\\build\\*.csproj"]
```

I created another image called add-msbuild that inherits from microsoft/iis. This way, I have an image with msbuild and nuget installed so that I can build my code. This dockerfile is run from the folder with the source code.

The problem: I can't get the `RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore"]` line to work. The CLI gives me this error: `Cannot determine the packages folder to restore NuGet packages. Please specify either -PackagesDirectory or -SolutionDirectory.`

Ok, fine. I'll add this parameter. I have tried the following ways:

`RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore", "PackagesDirectory"]
RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore", "-PackagesDirectory  'C:\site\packages'"]
RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore", "PackagesDirectory  'C:\site\packages'"]
RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore", "PackagesDirectory", "C:\site\packages"]

RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore", "-PackagesDirectory", "C:\site\packages"]`

But all ways give an error message. What am I doing wrong? I start the build with `docker build -t myproject .` if that makes any difference.

Edit: running the ls command from the `C:\build` folder returns this:

`Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         5/1/2017   1:41 PM                App_Data
d-----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM                App_Start
d-----        9/12/2017   3:28 PM                bin
d-----        9/15/2017  10:03 AM                Content
d-----        8/16/2017   1:50 PM                Controllers
d-----         9/1/2017   3:45 PM                DockerImage
d-----        9/15/2017  10:03 AM                fonts
d-----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM                Helpers
d-----         9/4/2017   4:32 PM                Models
d-----         9/1/2017   3:27 PM                obj
d-----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM                Properties
d-----        9/15/2017  10:03 AM                Scripts
d-----        8/16/2017   1:50 PM                Views
-a----        9/15/2017  10:10 AM            953 Dockerfile
-a----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM          32038 favicon.ico
-a----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM            111 Global.asax
-a----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM            601 Global.asax.cs
-a----        9/15/2017  10:03 AM          21422 myproject.csproj
-a----        9/15/2017  10:03 AM           2141 myproject.csproj.use
                                                 r
-a----         5/1/2017   1:41 PM            257 myproject.csproj.vsp
                                                 scc
-a----        5/30/2017   8:51 AM            148 myproject.v3.ncrunch
                                                 project
-a----         9/4/2017   4:32 PM            174 local-deploy.ps1
-a----        9/15/2017  10:03 AM           3006 packages.config
-a----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM           5277 Project_Readme.html
-a----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM            276 Startup.cs
-a----        9/15/2017  10:03 AM           8546 Web.config
-a----        5/12/2017   8:32 AM            442 Web.Debug.config
-a----         5/1/2017  11:55 AM           1168 Web.Release.config
-a----        5/12/2017   8:32 AM           1332 Web.Test.config`

Comment: Add a `RUN ls -al` before restore command and see if your see the correct files present in the working directory or not?

Comment: Powershell and Docker CLI do not consider `ls -al` a valid command, but I've added the output of `ls` if that helps.

Comment: Can you also try `RUN ["nuget.exe", "restore", "-PackagesDirectory", "C:\site\packages"]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it, but it doesn't work either...

Comment: Remove the last two run statements and run the image with powershell as the command. Get inside the container and manual run the commands and figure out what is wrong